# Openmp with dense IO operation, how to improve speed?

Tags: c++, io, openmp

my code is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  /*Reading for big data*/

  HeavyProcess();

  /*Writing for big data*/
}
```

I tried this:

```
#pragma omp parallel ordered schedule(dynamic)
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
#pragma omp ordered
/*Reading for big data*/

  HeavyProcess();
#pragma omp ordered
  /*Writing for big data*/
}
```

But it turn out to be very slow, the CPU usage looks like only one core is working.

If I simple use

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

I can get much higher CPU usage, but not 100%.

Is there any suggestions? Thanks very much!

Comment: I think we'll need a fair amount more information to be able to provide any meaningful help/advice.

Comment: I don't know many about openmp, but i want to say that 100% cpu usage is very rare, usually processors wastes many time to wait the RAM, so unless you are writing algorithm, which doesn't needs more data, that fits in processor's registers, you will be waiting on memory.

Comment: Read the data into a buffer with one thread, operate on the buffer in parallel (and without `ordered`), and then write the output buffer with one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Zboson's comment, you should set up a processing pipeline:

```
+---------+------------+---------+  
| Reading | Heavy      | Writing |  
| data    | Processing | Data    |  
+---------+------------+---------+
```

One thread starts off and reads data.
Data is passed to the processing data.
The Read thread reads in more data.

The Heavy Processing finishes and passes data to the Writing Data process.
The Reading Data process hands the data to the Heavy Processing process.
The Reading Data process reads in more data.

Research the concept of "double buffering".  In this case, you may want to have at least 3 buffers.  Pointers to the buffers are passed to each process.

To take advantage of any hardware acceleration for the I/O:

1. The Reading process reads in a buffer of raw data.
2. The Reading process then converts the raw data into internal format
   for the Heavy Processing process.
3. The Writing Data process should write the raw data into a buffer of
   formatted data.
4. The Writing Data process should write the formatted buffer as 1 I/O
   operation.

In smarter platforms, this will allow the OS to use devices like Direct Memory Access (DMA) controllers to read from I/O directly into memory.  This allows the process more time for crunching numbers.  Similarly with the writing.  The DMA controller can send data from the formatted data buffer to the output device independently of the processor.

Another suggestion is to have the primary processor handle the I/O and another processor, such as the one on a Graphics Controller board, perform the Heavy Processing.

Comment: so I should not parallelize at the for loop level? I should only parallelize the heavy processing unit, and the for loop is executed one-by-one? Could you give more detailed suggestions? And my code is running on 32core server, having no GPU. Thanks!

Comment: @user2727676, I think the assumption is that `Heavy Processing` has a for loop in it that can be parallelized instead. But then since your provided very little code it's impossible to say.

Comment: @user2727676, why not three separate for loops? One for reading, one for heavy processing, and one for writing. Then only parallelize the heavy processing one.

Comment: Parallelize the Heavy Processing.  Delegate the I/O to other cores / processors.  If you show an example of the Heavy Processing, we could help you with it, perhaps in another question.

Comment: @Z boson, HeavyProcessing does not contain loop, and the input data is very large, we cannot load them all into memory at one time.